# How to refactor long parameter lists into a parameter object in Java?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring, parameter-object, long-parameter-list

I am currently trying to refactor the getRGB,getSubimage and setRGB methods in the BufferedImage class. I am fairly new to Java and want to create good code; the problem is my parameter list is becoming very long and is causing problems for me. I found the parameter object as a solution however I am struggling to implement it.

Can I get a representation of how the following method can be improved with a parameter object;

`public void setRGB​(int startX,
                   int startY,
                   int w,
                   int h,
                   int[] rgbArray,
                   int offset,
                   int scansize)`

Comment: This will do just fine. If you want to, you can create another class with instance variables, a constructor to define them, and call this method with `setRGB(new Foo(parameters))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the information you provided, that's not much, what you want it's quite simple. So, you should wrap all these parameters inside a class (this class should follow the JavaBeans specifications and you should definitely should read about it, if you still didn't), like these:

```java
public class RGB {
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int w;
    private int h;
    private int[] rgbArray;
    private int offset;
    private int scansize;

// getters and setters

}
```

And then, your method will only receive an object that is a representation of this class:

```java
     public void setRGB​(RGB rgb) {...}
```